# Finding paths to both: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES and wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS variable needed for C++ compilation

Tags: debian, wxwidgets

On Debian based OS, how could I figure out both wxWidgets_LIBRARIES and wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS paths?

Indeed, I'm actually facing such error with cmake when trying to compile a software:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
  Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES
  wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:1008 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  src/pacakge_core/CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package)
```

Therefore, I'm searching for the correct paths to pass to my cmake command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. Apparently the cause of the error was the same as described here: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=47403

In Debian there no such `/usr/bin/grep` and `/usr/bin/egrep` so one has to build symlinks for those two commands:

```
$ ln -s /bin/grep /usr/bin/grep
$ ln -s /bin/egrep /usr/bin/egrep
```

After that, cmake runs smoothly, without having to be specified the two wxWidgets paths as they appeared in the original error message.